# SQL executemany() with python and an array and ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

I am struggling to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` with my current code:

```
def upload_to_database(ticker_collection):
  trend_data = []
  trend_data_table = "trend_data"
  trend_data_columns = "Ticker, Subreddit, Score, Rockets, Date"
  
  trend_data_sql = "INSERT INTO " + trend_data_table +\
                   " (" + trend_data_columns + ") VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) " +\
                   "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " +\
                   "Score = Score + %s, " +\
                   "Rockets = Rockets + %s"

  for ticker in ticker_collection:
    ticker_subreddit = ticker_collection[ticker]['subreddit']
    ticker_score = int(ticker_collection[ticker]['score'])
    ticker_rockets = int(ticker_collection[ticker]['rockets'])
    insert_date = datetime.date(datetime.now(est))
    
    ticker_data = (ticker, ticker_subreddit, ticker_score, ticker_rockets, insert_date, 1, 1)

    trend_data.append(ticker_data)
  
  the_db_cursor.executemany(trend_data_sql, trend_data)
  the_database.commit()
  
  return the_db_cursor.rowcount, "was inserted."
```

trend_data_sql is my query and towards the end there is Score and Rockets, effectively if an entry with the same Ticker and DateTime (my unique keys) exists I only want to update the score and rockets for that entry.

However, I am trying to do this with `executemany()` to save on db performance. I am a little stuck on how to incorporate `ON DUPLICATE KEY` with the for loop and `executemany()`.

Any guidance or advice would be much appreciated.

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `trend_data` (
  `Ticker` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Subreddit` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Rockets` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Table Indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `trend_data`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `Unique_Keys` (`Ticker`,`Date`,`Subreddit`) USING BTREE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```py
  trend_data_sql = "INSERT INTO " + trend_data_table +\
                   " (" + trend_data_columns + ") VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) " +\
                   "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " +\ 
                   "Score = Score + %s, " +\
                   "Rockets = Rockets + %s"
```

with

```py
  for ticker in ticker_collection:
    ...

    value = ...

    ...
    
    ticker_data = (ticker, ticker_subreddit, ticker_score, ticker_rockets, value, value)

    trend_data.append(ticker_data)
```

It was tested on MariaDB. If not working because you're using MySQL, I think you can try the following. (I could not test because I do not have MySQL though...)

```py
  trend_data_sql = "INSERT INTO " + trend_data_table +\
                   " (" + trend_data_columns + ") VALUES (%(ticker)s, %(reddit)s, %(score)s, %(rocket)s, %(date)s) " +\
                   "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " +\
                   "Score = Score + %(value)s, " +\
                   "Rockets = Rockets + %(value)s"

  for ticker in ticker_collection:
    ...
        
    ticker_data = {
      'ticker': ticker,
      'reddit': ticker_subreddit, 
      'score': ticker_score, 
      'rocket': ticker_rockets, 
      'date': insert_date, 
      'value': 1
    }    

    trend_data.append(ticker_data)
  
  the_db_cursor.executemany(trend_data_sql, trend_data)
  the_database.commit()
  
  return the_db_cursor.rowcount, "was inserted."


ticker_collection = {
    'a': {'subreddit': 'aa', 'score': 1, 'rockets': 11},
    'b': {'subreddit': 'bb', 'score': 2, 'rockets': 22},
    'c': {'subreddit': 'cc', 'score': 3, 'rockets': 33},
    'd': {'subreddit': 'dd', 'score': 4, 'rockets': 44}
}

print(upload_to_database(ticker_collection))
```

Comment: If I use this, this would add the current Score in the DB onto the Score? But the Score that I would be getting from the for loop is going to be different.

Comment: @alphadmon What's the variable `VALUE` in your example? If something else, you should append them to `trend_data` as well.

Comment: @alphadmon I made an edit. Please check it. :)

Comment: I just went through and made the updates as you described, they do make sense, however it is returning: (-1, 'was inserted.') and not inserting anything.

Comment: @alphadmon I checked it again. It works fine. Please replace your `trend_data_sql` by copy and paste, and modify `ticker_data` as well. You can replace `value` with simply `1` to test if it works.

Comment: Hmm, I copied it exactly and it is still failing on the same problem. Could this perhaps be an issue with the fact that score and rocket are INTs? And the value is set to "+ %s" I am making those values as follows: 

    ticker_score = int(ticker_collection[ticker]['score'])
    ticker_rockets = int(ticker_collection[ticker]['rockets'])

I also tried removing the int() and running - but running into the same issue.

Comment: @alphadmon Share me your table schema. And, do you reuse `ticker_score` and `ticker_rockets` as `value`s?

Comment: I have updated my initial question with the table schema and also edited the code as I now insert the date as a pure date rather than current timestamp. This is the error being produced: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Comment: And also no, i won't be reusing the ticker_score or ticker_rockets - that was a mistake sorry. I will be getting another integer and adding it on top of the current one.

Comment: I have also added the unique indexes to the original question.

Comment: @alphadmon I tested with edited code. It works fine. I added my testcase as well. Please check if your data have different properties with mine.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not really sure, that is exactly what I am using. Could it be the executemany() that is causing the issue? Not supporting ON DUPLICATE KEY or some such?

Comment: @alphadmon I tested your edited code and worked fine. Are other simple statements executed well?

Comment: @alphadmon How about to `str` your numeric values?

Comment: I tried changing all to string and still the same issue. If it is working for you with the complete code I posted something definitely has to be wrong on my side.

Comment: @alphadmon That's seriously weird... I posted my entire code.

Comment: So I copied your code which is exactly the same as mine and still the same issue. If I remove the executemany and replace it with execute and commit at the end of each for loop with ticker_data insted of the array tend_data, it works.

Comment: I wanted to avoid this because of the performance implications and I am really scratching my head as to why this doesn't works with executemany().

Comment: @alphadmon Besides the main topic, you do not need to `commit` every time you `execute`. You can `commit` after the last `execute`, thus, outside the loop.

Comment: If that is the case would the performance be unaffected if I had the commit outside the for loop? or would the execution complete the query each time anyway?

Comment: @alphadmon Each time. However, it will be applied once so it would be faster than the case `commit`ed every time. And definitely, it is much slower than `executemany`.

Comment: Hmm, I do see that you are using mariadb now actually. Perhaps that is the reason it can work. i am using import mysql.connector. Mostly because I plan to use a DigitalOcean managed MySQL database and they don't offer mariaDB managed yet.

Comment: @alphadmon Oh... Now I got the error as well... Let me check...

Comment: @alphadmon I edited (without test). I am not sure but give it a try...

Comment: Looks a little better just this error now: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%(value)s, Rockets = Rockets + %(value)s' at line 1, looking into it as it seems the rest should work.

Comment: @alphadmon Oh... Could `value` be predefined? How about to use something like `val` instead of `value`?

Comment: I thought that too and replaced with: "Score = Score + %(newscore)s, Rockets = Rockets + %(newrockets)s"

However this still results in the error, starting at "%(newscore)s," - I believe it has something to do with multiple ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE values?

Comment: I am marking your answer as the answer because it looks like with mariadb it works. It looks like it is a limitation of the library that DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE can't handle formatted placeholder variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228362/discussion-between-ghchoi-and-alphadmon).